# ASP.NET: Using ValidationSummary with Gridview controls

Tags: asp.net

I have added some RequiredFieldValues to the EditItemTemplates for some columns in a GridView and for each I have set a ValidationGroup. The RequiredFieldValidators fire for the controls.

However, I'd like the errors to appear down in the normal area of the page (which is outside the grid) and was hoping to use a ValidationSummary to pick up those errors and display them there rather than with the column data.

The ValidationSummary seems to ignore the error and leave them where they are.

Has anyone had this problem and solved it?

Thanks

Comment: The `<asp:ValidationSummary>` control is specific to each `ValidationGroup`.  If you don't specify a group, then it will only show those validators who also don't have a group specified - and conversely a summary with a group specified will only show the error for validators of the same group. Not sure there is a way for a summary control to pick up validators from ALL groups

Comment: I guess the obvious question is whether you actually need different validation groups?  Can you get away with not having any groups set?

Comment: I have the groups set the same, but it's still not working.

Comment: So all the validators **and** the validation summary have exactly the same group (with the same case)?  Have you tried with absolutely no group specified (not even having the attribute)?